# Passing a sheets codename as a parameter in the range function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, reference, range

**IN VBA**

```
Function SNAME(number As String) As String
    Dim WORD$
    WORD = "Sheet" + number
'    SNAME = Worksheets(1).CodeName
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).CodeName = WORD Then SNAME = Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Function
```

**IN EXCEL**

```
=SUMIFS((SNAME(19)!$T$2:$T$9962),(SNAME(19)!$A$2:$A$9962),"=31",(SNAME(19)!$C$2:$C$9962),"<="&EDATE(TODAY(),-12))
```

**Purpose:**

The idea here is that I want to pass the sheets name to the range function based on its code name. the VBA function SNAME seems functional and returns the worksheet's name based on the VBA object code name. When I try to combine that with the range function in the equation, there seems to be an error I'm unsure how to resolve. When I replace SNAME(19) with the sheet name the Equation executes properly.

**Goal:**

I need to be able to reference the sheet using its code name to avoid future errors of individuals changing the name of the sheets. I'd really appreciate any advice someone might have on the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that. However - if someone renames as sheet is that a problem? Excel typically adjusts existing formulas when that happens.

Comment: With VBA I'm able to access the sheet's name based on the sheet's object name or "CodeName" being sheet[insert number]. Thus through a VBA function, I think it should be simple enough to send back the sheet's name to the Function on the Excel sheet. I think the error I'm having might be a translation issue from one function retrieving the sheet's name to the next function that performs the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Excel automatically corrects the formula if any name used there has been changed. So I'm not sure whether you need this construction. Anyway, to make it work we have to change `SNAME(19)!$T$2:$T$9962` to something like `INDIRECT("'" & SNAME(19) & "'!$T$2:$T$9962")`.

To make this cleaner, let's put quoting inside the function `SNAME`. Also, I'd change the type of `number` to `Variant` and put `Exit For` on success:

```
Function SNAME(number) As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim WORD$
    WORD = "Sheet" & number
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.CodeName = WORD Then 
            SNAME = "'" & sh.Name & "'"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
End Function
```

In the formula, I would use `LET` to ease editing the function call and to call it once:

```
=LET(sh, SNAME(19),
    SUMIFS(
        INDIRECT(sh & "!$T$2:$T$9962"), 
        INDIRECT(sh & "!$A$2:$A$9962"),
        "=31",
        INDIRECT(sh & "!$C$2:$C$9962"),
        "<=" & EDATE(TODAY(),-12)
    )
)
```

Comment: I did as instructed however it's giving me back the #NAME error. I double-checked the grammar and spelling in notepad and it all checks out. I think your advice might be the right approach but I'm unsure of the issue accuring.

Comment: Sorry, Macros were disabled but now that they're enabled it gives me #VALUE error.

Comment: @ChristianPrieto Try to do it in parts. See what is the output of `=SNAME(19)`, then check `=INDIRECT(SNAME(19) & "!$T$2:$T$9962)`, then `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(SNAME(19) & "!$T$2:$T$9962), ...)`, then `=LET(....)` if your version of Excel supports it (this is optional).

Comment: SNAME(19) returns #value error
=INDIRECT(SNAME(19) & "!$T$2:$T$9962) returns #value error
=Let(...(Sumifs(...))) returns #value error

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the code name `Sheet19` in the workbook where the macro is placed?

Comment: Yes, I tested the code in VBA and it returned 'worksheetname' in the immediate output window.

Comment: Where exactly have you placed the macro? Is it a module or a code page of a sheet?

Comment: macro is in a module.

Comment: @ChristianPrieto I can't recreate #VALUE error with a formula `=SNAME(...)` and I'm out of options. I work with Office 365, Excel version 16.0. No #VALUE error happens in this env. Maybe you should add more debugging details in the original post. Especially when it goes about `=SNAME(...)` formula output in a cell.